# how to serve files over http2 but fetch API data over http1 in express

Tags: node.js, express, http2

i am using express in my application. i want to upgrade to http2 to serve all the static resources over http2. but i need to fetch data from 3rd party apis which may not support http2 yet so i want this connection over http1.

- from browser to express , the connection should be h2.(for static files)
- from express to third parties , connection should be h1(for data)

how do i achieve this ?

i have tried using `node-http-proxy` and `request` to make calls to third parties from express. but they are giving errors.

Comment: *but they are giving errors.* - what errors?

Comment: can't set deprecated header : connection